# Difference between duration units that end with an "s" or not (e.g. "day" vs. "days")

Tags: javascript, luxon

Using Luxon.js, is there a difference between duration units that end with an "s" and those that do not?

For example:

```
DateTime.now().plus({ day: 1 });
```

vs.

```
DateTime.now().plus({ days: 1 });
```

My tests seem to indicate that there is no difference, but I want to be sure. I haven't found anything in the documentation about this.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's [_"the object argument to Duration.fromObject()"_](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeplus), which is only [documented](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#durationfromobject) to accept the plural form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same.

If you check the [source for the `Duration` object](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/3125686af82d9a25c7267a1cf1eb838a3d41144f/src/duration.js#L399) you can see that there's a mapping which converts `day` to `days`, `minute` to `minutes` and so on for converting all singular time periods to plural.

Answer (score 1):

Poking through the source, if you pass an object to `plus`, that eventually gets standardized [here](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/3125686af82d9a25c7267a1cf1eb838a3d41144f/src/duration.js#L399) to the plural form:

```
static normalizeUnit(unit) {
    const normalized = {
      year: "years",
      years: "years",
      quarter: "quarters",
      quarters: "quarters",
      . . .
      millisecond: "milliseconds",
      milliseconds: "milliseconds",
    }[unit ? unit.toLowerCase() : unit];

    if (!normalized) throw new InvalidUnitError(unit);

    return normalized;
  }
```

[The object is given to `Duration.fromObject`](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/3125686af82d9a25c7267a1cf1eb838a3d41144f/src/duration.js#L287), and then given to the above function.